# How to raise to the power of

Tags: c, math

I am very new to C

I am trying to put something to the power of something

eg. 5^3=125;

but when I code

```
#include <math.h>
...

printf("%d", 5^3);
```

I get 6. Am i doing something fundamentally wrong??

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B - you'll find `^` in the bitwise category

Comment: Please, don't invent your own syntax. ;-)

Answer (score 20):

`^` is the bitwise XOR operator in C.

`5` is `101` in binary representation and `3` is `011`. So `101 XOR 011 = 110`, which is `6` in decimal.

What you want is `pow(5,3)` (which is available after including `math.h` as you did). Note however that it acts on doubles not integer, so your return value will be a floating point and in general not exact. If you need exact integer exponentiation, then you either have to use an additional library or implement your own power-function. This is not that hard, for an algorithm see [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Standard C does not include a function for integer exponentiation. Anyway with integer exponentiation it is important to take care of [overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), which may happen already for small input values.

Also to print the returned double you either have to cast the double to an int `printf("%d", (int)pow(5,3))` or print it as floating point `printf("%f", pow(5,3))`

Comment: I've just tried this but I get 
Error 1 error C2668: 'pow' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
What does this mean? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please post the full error message? Also are you using c or c++? Anyway you can try `pow((double)5, (double)3)` to explicitly state the types. Or `pow(5.0f, 3.0f)`.

Comment: 'pow((double)5, (double)3)' seems to have fixed it. I am working on c. Am I alright to do something like this?   
'int a=pow((double)5, (double)3);'
   'int *b;'
   'b=(int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*((a)+1));'

Comment: @user3139744; Yes. But do not cast the return value of `malloc`. It should be`'b = malloc(sizeof(int)*((a)+1));`.

Answer (score 4):

`^` is a XOR operator in C.

Instead you should use the `pow` function from `math.h`, however `pow` returns double

```
#include <math.h>
...

printf("%d", (int)pow(5, 3));
```

Answer (score 4):

There is **no operator for exponentiation (power) in C**. `^` is used as a bitwise `XOR` operator in C language. Doing `5^3` will return `6`, not `125`. For exponentiation you can use standard library function `pow`.
Signature:

```
double pow(double x, double y);
```

Header:

```
#include <math.h>
```

Change

```
printf("%d", 5^3);
```

to

```
printf("%d",(int)pow(5,3));
```

In C++ do not use `<math.h>`. Instead you can use `<cmath>`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `pow(5,3)`.

You're using the bitwise XOR (`^`) operator there: in binary that's `101 ^ 011`, which is `110`, or `6` (your current answer) in denary.

Answer (score 3):

Others have already recommended using the `pow` function from `math.h` because `^` is not the correct operator for performing power of. Alternatively you can also write your own power function just for fun.

```
int power(int base, int exp)
{
    int result = 1;
    while(exp) 
    {   
        result = result * base; 
        exp--; 
    }
    return result;
```

Inside main:

```
printf("%d\n", power(5,3));
```

In this case you don't have to use the cast operator as `pow()` doesn't work with int.