# Looping operations

Tags: c, for-loop, function-calls

I would like to write something like this;

```
for (op1 in (plus, minus, times, divby, exponent)) {
    printf("%d", a op1 b);
}
```

so that what actually ends up being executed is something like this

```
printf("%d", a + b);
printf("%d", a - b);
printf("%d", a * b);
printf("%d", a / b);
printf("%d", a ^ b);
```

How can I write this?

Comment: I tried defining the operations as macro variables (#define plus +), but I can't figure out how to put the operations in an array that I can loop over

Comment: btw `a ^ b` is not exponent, it's xclusive OR. You could loop on a list of function pointers accepting 2 arguments for instance.

Comment: These operators are, in fact, functions that take two numbers and output just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array of function pointers would do.

```
double plus(int a, int b);
double minus(int a, int b);
double times(int a, int b);
double divby(int a, int b);
double exponent(int a, int b);

typedef double (*p_fun)(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 10;
    p_fun pa[] = {plus, minus, times, divby, exponent};
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(pa)/sizeof(p_fun); i++ )
    {
        printf("%f\n", pa[i](a, b));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you've not posted any code, I'm not going to write any, but will be happy to help with some concepts which you can turn into working code.

1. Write functions to perform individual operations (*addition, subtraction, multiplication etc*).
2. Take an array of [function pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer), initialize that with individual functions you want to perform.
3. Loop over the array and pass the required variables to the function call to get desired output.

Something like (*pseudo-code*)

```
funcptr arr[SIZE] = { func1, func2, func3... };

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE ; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", arr[i](a, b));
}
```

That said, just a note, `a ^ b` is **not** an *"exponent"* operator in C, as you might have expected. It is bitwise XOR. You can make use of [`pow()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pow) to get that done.

FYI, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20872689/2173917) for related information.